# php - Get taxonomy posts and show to category without using custom taxonomy slug

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have nhl news website and I create custom taxonomy for each season (ex 2014-15)

```
function wptp_register_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy( 'season', 'post',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name'              => 'Seasons',
                'singular_name'     => 'Season',
                'search_items'      => 'Search Season',
                'all_items'         => 'All Season',
                'edit_item'         => 'Edit Season',
                'update_item'       => 'Update',
                'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Season',
                'new_item_name'     => 'New Season',
                'menu_name'         => 'Seasons',
            ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'sort' => true,
            'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'season' ),
            'show_admin_column' => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wptp_register_taxonomy' );

add_filter('pre_get_posts','season_archive');
function better_editions_archive( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_tax( 'season' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' ) );
        $query->set( 'tax_query',
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'season',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'intl',
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                )
            )
        );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

EX When I want to get for 2013-2014 posts:

```
http://localhost/nhl/news/?season=20132014
```

Now what I want is when I go to the category news without taxonomy

```
http://localhost/nhl/news/
```

to show only current season posts for ex 20142015 without using custom taxonomy slug

Thank you